# How to remove all folders with a specific name recursively from all sub directories?

Tags: linux, search, find

Here is a sample of some directory paths

```
find . -name .svn;

./application/views/scripts/soft/.svn
./application/views/scripts/sitemap/.svn
./application/views/scripts/register/.svn
./application/views/scripts/home/.svn
./application/views/scripts/terms-of-service/.svn
./application/views/scripts/promotions/.svn
./application/views/scripts/test/.svn
./application/views/scripts/privacy-policy/.svn
./application/views/scripts/services/.svn
./application/views/scripts/mobile/.svn
./application/test/.svn
./application/public/.svn
```

I want to remove all `.svn` folders from all this directories at once from the current root directory I'm in.

Any deas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do (added `-type d` to your find command to get folders only)

`` rm -rf  `find . -type d -name .svn` ``

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name \*.svn -type f -delete
```